# Having an issue with fetching data from backend using react useffect hook and axios. getting a 404 error (not found)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am working on building a Netflix clone and I am having an issue with getting my backend API to come up using the useffect hook in react. I am getting a 404 error (not found). I have added my route as a proxy in the package.json file. this is a get request to get a list of movies I have put into my database in MongoDB. I do get the list when I use postman. don't understand why I am getting this error. please share any ideas.

**package.json file **

```
  "name": "new",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "sass": "^1.35.1",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8800/api/"
}
```

**Home.jsx**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Featured from "../../components/featured/Featured";
import List from "../../components/list/List";
import Navbar from "../../components/navbar/Navbar";
import axios from "axios";
import "./home.scss";

const Home = ({ type }) => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  const [lists, setLists] = useState([]);
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  const [genre, setGenre] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getRandomLists = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(
          `lists${type ? "?type=" + type : ""}${
            genre ? "&genre=" + genre : ""
          }`,
          {
            headers: {
              token:
                "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjYzYTA1ZjliZTRiZmEzYTBhOWMxYTQ5ZCIsImlzQWRtaW4iOnRydWUsImlhdCI6MTY3MTcxMjgyMCwiZXhwIjoxNjcyMTQ0ODIwfQ.W2e-RJ0XIQIVgGT47yhEOVOtWbdR5yYk11zmvN3vLzk",
            },
          }
        );
        console.log(res);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    getRandomLists();
  }, [type, genre]);
  return (
    <div className="home">
      <Navbar />
      <Featured type={type} />
      <List />
      <List />
      <List />
      <List />
      <List />
      <List />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

**index.js backend**

```
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const authRoute = require("./routes/auth");
const userRoute = require("./routes/users");
const movieRoute = require("./routes/movies");
const listRoute = require("./routes/lists");
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());
dotenv.config();
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => console.log("DB Connection Successful!"))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

app.use(express.json());

app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);
app.use("/api/users", userRoute);
app.use("/api/movies", movieRoute);
app.use("/api/lists", listRoute);

app.listen(8800, () => {
  console.log("backend server is running on port 8800");
});
```

** list.js in backend **

````
router.get("/", verify, async (req, res) => {
  const typeQuery = req.query.type;
  const genreQuery = req.query.genre;
  let list = [];

  try {
    if (typeQuery) {
      if (genreQuery) {
        list = await List.aggregate([
          { $sample: { size: 10 } },
          { $match: { type: typeQuery, genre: genreQuery } },
        ]);
      } else {
        list = await List.aggregate([
          { $sample: { size: 10 } },
          { $match: { type: typeQuery } },
        ]);
      }
    } else {
      list = await List.aggregate([{ $sample: { size: 10 } }]);
    }
    res.status(200).json(list);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json(error);
  }
});```
````

Comment: It's probably an issue with your express app and your react app having different adresses. You do not specify in axios get call which domain/port to access

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue my token had expired. I just had to go back to postman and login and get a new token from postman.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).